# SQL multiple count lookups in same query, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a row in my database, its called 'type' that multiple rows already in the database and it can have the same value. The valuecan be a number of 1-12 and many rows have the same value. and I want to create a query that looks at the amount of rows that has the same number. Sorts the outcome so I know which type is more popular. Number of rows of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.
The basic query would be SELECT count(type) from mytable where type is 1, for example and then loop though each type 1-12. However is there a good way to make it all into one query, instead of looping though each type in separate for-loop. Returning a list of 12 items based on the result of all counts for example?

Comment: Your question is a pain to read. Format it nicely, include sample data, the query you tried and the desired result set. Not one huge block of text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic `GROUP BY` and an `ORDER BY`:

```
Select Type, Count(*) Cnt
From MyTable
Group By Type
Order By Cnt Desc
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this tomorrow!